# Azure streaming analytics query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have the following query that takes an input from an IoT weather station and outputs to Power Bi:

```
WITH machinelearning AS (
   SELECT EventEnqueuedUtcTime, Temperature, Humidity, WindSpeed, WindGust, Pressure, Rain, machinelearning(Temperature, Humidity, Pressure) as result from [CwrtCelynWeather]
)
Select WindSpeed, WindGust, CAST (result.[Pressure] AS FLOAT) AS Pressure, Rain, System.Timestamp time, CAST (result.[temperature] AS FLOAT) AS temperature, CAST (result.[humidity] AS FLOAT) AS humidity, CAST (result.[Scored Probabilities] AS FLOAT ) AS 'probabalities of rain'
Into [weatherPBi2]
From machinelearning
```

My question is how would i convert the following to a percentage?

```
CAST (result.[Scored Probabilities] AS FLOAT ) AS 'probabalities of rain'
```

At the moment it returns a decimal of 0.45, but i want to have it send 45.0. I have tried the following:

```
CAST (result.[Scored Probabilities] AS FLOAT ) *100 AS 'probabalities of rain'
```

&

```
CAST (result.[Scored Probabilities*100] AS FLOAT ) AS 'probabalities of rain'
```

But the streaming analytics complains.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: what was the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody else runs into the same problem, here is my solution:

```
100 * CAST (result.[Scored Probabilities] AS FLOAT ) AS 'probabalities of rain'
```

This worked fine.